# Tracking Graph edges changes history

Tags: database-design, relational-database, graph-databases

i have a graph and transactions which change the relationship between the graph nodes and i need to keep tracking of this changes over time. Kinde of queries i need to execute:

1. I want to see the graph version before the transaction X
2. I want to see the latest version of the graph.

-The graph nodes have name and id
-The relationship between the nodes is just number

- Transaction can change the number and can delete it also so no more relation between the two nodes.

Any ideas where to start and which basic schema i can start from?

Best regards

Comment: see [where to start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your system, there several solutions that may or may not work for you.

Version information can be a simple integer, or a date/timestamp value.  If a simple integer you can go back 1 transaction fairly easily if you know the version number of the transaction.  A timestamp will make it slightly harder to go back exactly 1 version since you'll have to find the version first, but a simple list of timestamps would suffice.

1. When a transaction changes the relationships to make a new version, first make a copy of the relationships, and tag it with the new version.  Locate the copy associated with the version of interest.
2. Add version information to the edges, maybe something like start-version and end-version.  If end-version is empty then consider that the edge is in the latest/current version.  Otherwise if the version of interest is in between some edge's start-version, end-version pair, then this edge is part of that version.  To delete a relationship, you fill in the end-version field pair to mark it no longer in the current version (instead of removing the relationship).
3. Keep the whole list of transactions (changes) and re-run them to find versions of interest.  This would be like doing Event Sourcing, where events are what is persisted, and they can be replayed to recreate some point in time.

More broadly, a versioning scheme can either make copies associated with versions, or, can make deltas, which describe the differences between one version and the next and allow one version to be recreated by following deltas, while only storing the initial version (or in another approach, only storing the current version).

Other areas to look into: source code version control systems, and how those work to allow retrieval of the latest and older versions.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. As last result of my system i want to see how my graph was at any point of time. So some kind of going back in history. My graph can contains 2000 nodes.